# Proper singleton class implementation

Tags: c#, class, design-patterns, properties

I started my design patterns learning with a singleton class. Could you explain me the difference between the following Instance property implementations?

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton _instance;
    public static Singleton Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new Singleton());
}
```

```
public class Singleton
{
    public static Singleton Instance => _instance.Value;

    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> _instance =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());
}
```

Comment: The first example is not thread-safe. The second example is.

Comment: https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singleton pattern has evolved quite a bit since is first presentation in the GoF book.
The classical implementation of the pattern requires a static way to access the instance, example given:

```
 public class Singleton
 {
     public static Singleton Instance => ....

     public virtual void CallMe() { ... }
 }
```

However this approach has a big drawback when it's time to write tests. A "Client" class would reference the singleton in the following way:

```
public class Client
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
         Singleton.Instance.CallMe();
    }
}
```

With this shape it is impossible to mock the implementation of the CallMe method and write a unit test for the DoSomething method.

What should be done to realize a singleton instance of a class is to leave it up to the IoC container, in this way:

```
 public class Singleton
 {
    //no static properties
    public virtual void CallMe() { ... }
  }

  public class Client
  {
     private readonly Singleton _singleton;
     public Client(Singleton singleton)
     {
        _singleton = singleton;
     }
     public void DoSomething() => _singleton.CallMe();
  }

  //where you declare your services
  builder.Services.AddSingleton<Singleton>();
  builder.Services.AddScoped<Client>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to your request the way I implemented it recently. I hope this's the SOLID  answer that everyone's searching for!

```
using System;

namespace NamespaceThatYouAreHopefullyAlreadyUsing.CommonSlashUtilsWhatEvz
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Abstracts a thread safe, high perf singleton which is leveraged exclusively via inheritance 
  /// </summary>
  /// <typeparam name="ClassToMakeIntoSingleton">Any class that the should become a singleton.</typeparam>
  public abstract class LazySingleton<ClassToMakeIntoSingleton> where ClassToMakeIntoSingleton : new()
  {
    // Make sure no more than 1 instance of ClassToMakeIntoSingleton can be instantiated during each request without throwing a runtime exception.
    private static int _instanceCount = 0;

    // Lazily load the instance which always points to the same/first new ClassToMakeIntoSingleton();
    private static readonly Lazy<ClassToMakeIntoSingleton> _instance = new Lazy<ClassToMakeIntoSingleton>(() => new ClassToMakeIntoSingleton(), true);

    /// <summary>
    /// Only allow an instance to be generated even if new keyword is used, since it could potentially cause major errors if the class is instantiated more
    /// than once during this apps runtime.
    /// </summary>    
    protected LazySingleton()
    {
      // Make sure not more than 1 instance of ClassToMakeIntoSingleton can be instantiated without throwing a runtime exception.
      if (_instanceCount++ > 1)
      {
        // Shouldn't happen unless _instance doesn't use Lazy<ClassToMakeIntoSingleton> in the future after future development changes..
        throw new AccessViolationException(string.Format("An invalid attempt to instantiate the {0} singleton more than once was made.", typeof(ClassToMakeIntoSingleton)));
      }
    }

    // Since this abstraction will only be used to get a single instance by nature, provide a static Get() for composition sake and allow a convienient
    // facade around allowing composition whenever an existing ClassToMakeIntoSingleton instance has already been instantiated.
    protected ClassToMakeIntoSingleton Get()
    {
      return _instance.Value;
    }
  }
}
```

To be used like

```
// Automatically become a qualified singleton via inheritance from LazySingleton defined above 
// PLEASE SEAL ME WHEN EXTENDING FROM LazySingleton!
public sealed class InheritingClassNameHerePlease : LazySingleton<InheritingClassNameHerePlease>
{
   ...implementation to be called only once here
}
```

Then, call your class that you wish to become a singleton via way of

```
// When the creation of the singleton is explicit...
var inheritingClassNameHerePlease = new InheritingClassNameHerePlease();

 // Or, whenever you're knowingly using an already existing instance, it would be more semantic to use the following facade...
    var inheritingClassNameHerePlease = InheritingClassNameHerePlease.Get();
```

> **Note:** using `new InheritingClassNameHerePlease()` vs `InheritingClassNameHerePlease.Get()` do the exact same thing, but since only 1 NEW class will be made according to the definition of a singleton, access via the **new** InheritingClassNameHerePlease() keyword should technically only be used once during initial instantiation for compositions  sake, but can be avoided by simply always calling `InheritingClassNameHerePlease.Get()` instead of `new InheritingClassNameHerePlease()`.

Comment: @Alex thank you! It made me feel good once I got it done, I wanted to share with the world

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton _instance;
    public static Singleton Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new Singleton());
}
```

The above implementation of sigleton is not thred safe. As static variables are always shared by all the threads in the process. So two threads can evaluate that `_instance` is equal to null and two threads will create two instances of Singleton which is not eligible.

The following implementation is thread safe as it uses `Lazy<T>`:

```
public class Singleton
{
    public static Singleton Instance => _instance.Value;

    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> _instance =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());
}
```

As [msdn says about Lazy](https://public%20class%20Singleton%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20public%20static%20Singleton%20Instance%20=%3E%20_instance.Value;%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20static%20readonly%20Lazy%3CSingleton%3E%20_instance%20=%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20new%20Lazy%3CSingleton%3E(()%20=%3E%20new%20Singleton());%20%7D):

> You can use one of the simple constructors whose default behavior is
> to create a **thread-safe Lazy** object, so that **only one
> instance of the lazily instantiated object is created no matter how
> many threads try to access it**.